# Where to look in Xcode for debug information

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I’m new to iOS, Xcode development… and I’m having trouble trying to figure why my app is failing at a specific point.

I have a starting ViewController called MainMenuViewController which currently has a label with the application title and two buttons. Each button acts as a segue action show to two more ViewControllers.

The App builds successfully when the MainMenuViewController appears if I click on the first button it takes me to the next ViewController and all actions on this and subsequent ViewControllers that lead on from these views as well as segue actions that take me back to the MainMenuViewController from any of these Views work correctly.

From the MainMenuViewController if I click the second button the segue action fails and Xcode points to `class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {` line in the file AppDelegate.swift.

Where should I be looking to find out why the app failed?

Comment: Can you post the actual error message?

Comment: Find the Breakpoint Navigator view on the left and set an exception breakpoint (plus sign at bottom).  That should cause the program to stop at the line where the error occurs instead of the useless one in AppDelegate.

Comment: There is only one message I can see. OS Simulator just switches to Xcode and the line I mention is highlighted in green. At the end of the line it displays Thread 1: signal SIGABRT.

Comment: Set breakpoint in 1st line of the ViewController that second button segues to. It never hits breakpoint. I have following in debug window.. 2015-08-16 15:53:21.596 MileageLogger[2628:1117763] Could not load the "first" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "com.qdpbdesign.MileageLogger"
2015-08-16 15:53:26.284 MileageLogger[2628:1117763] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<MileageLogger.FuelIntakeViewController 0x7c441e10> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key buttonClearFuelEntry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... figured it out... The two views had some commonality so when I completed the first view I copied the common controls over to the other view. Unknown to me it not only transferred the control but also had the SentEvent that referenced the first view controller. These were not replaced by the new references I constructed but were just added to. Deleting the original references fixed the issue.